# Dynamic variable from each method

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I have an array that I would like to iterate and create dynamic variables. Further, I would like to loop it. any idea how to achieve it?

code:

```
collection = ["s", "g", "l"]

collection.each do |variable_name|
   devan_'#{variable_name}' = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
   devan_'#{variable_name}'.each do |s1|
     puts "from #{variable_name} we got #{s1}"
   end
end
```

exception

```
 syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end
   devan_'#{variable_name}' = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
```

Comment: Could you add an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Assigning data to dynamic variables sounds to me like a perfect use-case of a Hash.

Comment: ...in part because, since Ruby v1.8, it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other commenters suggested, you may need a hash instead of a dynamic variable:

```
collection = ["s", "g", "l"]

collection.each do |key|
   devan[key] = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
   devan[key].each do |s1|
     puts "from #{key} we got #{s1}"
   end
end
```

With a hash, you get "for free" an arsenal of easy to use methods, which would otherwise be more cumbersome with dynamic variables. For example:

```
# Add an element to the array for the 's' key:
devan['s'].push 'h4'

# Add an element to the array for each key:
devan.each_key { |k| devan[k].push 'h5' }

# Print array length for each key:
devan.each { |k,v| puts v.length }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Setting Dynamic Instance Variables from Inside a Block

The type of metaprogramming you're trying to do has to be done a bit differently in Ruby than some other languages. In Ruby, you can't simply append a string to a variable name on the left hand side of an assignment and have it recognized as a valid variable within the current namespace. This is even more problematic when scope gates are involved; even if it worked, you'd end up with block-local variables that wouldn't exist outside the current block.

As an example of how to work around this language design choice, consider this dynamic approach leveraging [Object#instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to define the variable, and [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to read it:

```
%w[s g l].map do |ext|
  varname = "@devan_#{ext}"
  instance_variable_set varname, ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
  puts "#{varname} = #{instance_variable_get varname}"
end

[@devan_s, @devan_g, @devan_l]
#=> [["h1", "h2", "h3"], ["h1", "h2", "h3"], ["h1", "h2", "h3"]]
```

By using this approach to set or read instance variables, you're able to pass your string interpolation *as an argument* rather than as the left-hand side element of an assignment or method call. You just need to name your variables with a leading `@` symbol.

By using instance variables, you're also ensuring that the new variables are created (and continue to live) outside the local block's scope. If that's not actually what you want, consider using [Binding#local_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set) and [Binding#local_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) instead.

Comment: In all my years of experience, I have _never_ seen a case when I have an array of values and dynamically setting instance variables like this would have worked better than a hash or array.